# What is known about this well-ordering of the rationals in a finite interval?

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, rational-numbers

Given any interval $I=(a,b) \subset \mathbb R^+$, we may order the rationals in $I$ with a *denominator-first lexicographic order*, as follows:  First, we list, in increasing order of numerator, all $q \in I$ that have a denominator of $1$ when written in lowest terms (if any); then we list all $q \in I$ that have a denominator of $2$ when written in lowest terms (if any); and so forth.  For example, the rationals in $(5,6)$ would be enumerated as:
$$\frac{11}{2}, \frac{16}{3}, \frac{17}{3}, \frac{21}{4}, \frac{23}{4}, \frac{26}{5}, \frac{27}{5}, \frac{28}{5}, \frac{29}{5}, \frac{31}{6}, \frac{35}{6} \dots$$
This is obviously a well-ordering, and is similar in spirit to the Farey sequences of order $n$, although they are not the same thing.  (In particular the order I am considering here is not compatible with the usual order $<$ on $\mathbb Q$.)

[It is known, for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_within_an_interval), that if $a,b$ are irrational then the "first" rational in $(a,b)$ (in the sense of this order) can be computed by comparing the continued fraction representations of $a$ and $b$.

My questions:

> 1. Does this order have a standard name?  "Denominator-first
>      lexicographic order" is precise, but clumsy.  Something non-descriptive but with a person's name attached to it (in the flavor of "Farey sequence") would be fine.
> 2. What else (if anything) is known about this order?  For example, is
>      there a way to compute the *second* (or *n*th) rational in $(a,b)$
>      using continued fractions or something else?

If I knew a good answer to the first question, I suspect I could probably make some headway on my own with the second question.  (Without a distinguished name, this turns out to be very hard to Google.)

For those who are interested in the background to this question, I am working on a paper about locating the first rational square in an interval $(a,a+1)$ (where "first" is relative to this order).  I've found lots of interesting results but have been unsuccessful at finding related prior work to make connections to.

**Edited to add:**
With less than 8 hours to go on the bounty, I thought I might provide some more details about the kind of directions I am interested in.  Tad's answer below suggests looking at the "canonical" interval $(0,1)$, but what about intervals of the form $(\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n+1})$?  Consider by way of example $(\sqrt{13},\sqrt{14})$.  The rationals in this interval are, in this well-ordering,
$$\frac{11}3, \frac{26}7, \frac{29}8, \frac{37}{10}, \frac{40}{11}, \frac{41}{11}, \frac{47}{13}, \frac{48}{13},\dots $$

Some things are easy to see:  For example, the sequence of denominators 
$$(d_n): 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 11, 13, 13, \dots$$
may have both skips and repeats.  As noted above, the first term in the sequence (namely  $\frac{11}3$) can be computed by comparing the continued fractions for $\sqrt{13}$ and $\sqrt{14}$.  Is there an analogous way to compute the second or *n*th term in the sequence?  Are there any other known properties of these sequences?

Comment: related to [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The "canonical" interval to try is $(0,1)$.  Based on that, go to the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) and look up the sequence of numerators (which is the concatenation, for all $k\ge2$, of the $\phi(k)$ integers less than $k$ which are relatively prime to $k$: $1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5,\ldots$)  Your sequence appears as sequence [A038566](http://oeis.org/A038566); there are a ton of references there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you have any ideas how to deal with intervals that are not of the form $(n,n+1)$?  For example, it isn't clear to me at all how to adapt the "canonical" interval to the case of one of the form $(\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n+1})$.

Comment: The same approach works for any interval $(a,b)$ (list in order of increasing denominators, then increasing numerators).  For a given denominator $q$ you need to find the least $p$ such that $p/q> a$, which is $aq+1$ if $a q\in \Bbb Z$ and $\lceil a q\rceil$ otherwise.  However, while there's a chance there's a formula for the $n$-th rational in the list when $(a,b)=(0,1)$, there's not much chance when $(a,b)=(e,\pi)$.

Comment: Yes, I know that one can list the rationals that way for any interval -- that was in the original question.  I am wondering if that ordering has a name, and what (if anything) is known about how that ordering behaves.